# how to add label to flutter curved navigation bar icons?

Tags: flutter

add label to this icons items

```
Icon(Icons.home, size: 30)
```

add label Home

```
Icon(Icons.videocam_outlined, size: 30)
```

add label Live Cam

Comment: Are you used [this](https://pub.dev/packages/curved_navigation_bar) dependency? or what do you use or share extra code

Answer (score 1):

There is no any direct way add to label in curved navigation as of now.

but You can try this,

```
     Container(
          height: 50,
          child: Column(
            children: [Icon(Icons.add, size: 30), Text("Page 1")],
          ),
        ),
```

Whole code,

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:curved_navigation_bar/curved_navigation_bar.dart';

    void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: BottomNavBar()));

    class BottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _BottomNavBarState createState() => _BottomNavBarState();
    }

    class _BottomNavBarState extends State<BottomNavBar> {
      int _page = 0;
      GlobalKey<CurvedNavigationBarState> _bottomNavigationKey = GlobalKey();

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
              key: _bottomNavigationKey,
              index: 0,
              height: 60.0,
              items: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [Icon(Icons.add, size: 30), Text("Page 1")],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [Icon(Icons.list, size: 30), Text("Page 2")],
                  ),
                ),
                Icon(Icons.compare_arrows, size: 30),
                Icon(Icons.call_split, size: 30),
                Icon(Icons.perm_identity, size: 30),
              ],
              color: Colors.white,
              buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
              backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
              animationCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
              animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
              onTap: (index) {
                setState(() {
                  _page = index;
                });
              },
              letIndexChange: (index) => true,
            ),
            body: Container(
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(_page.toString(), textScaleFactor: 10.0),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      child: Text('Go To Page of index 1'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        final CurvedNavigationBarState? navBarState =
                            _bottomNavigationKey.currentState;
                        navBarState?.setPage(1);
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ));
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I just create a new package to add label to Curved Navigation Bar: [curved_labeled_navigation_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/curved_labeled_navigation_bar)

Code example:

```
bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
  items: [
    CurvedNavigationBarItem(
      child: Icon(Icons.home),
      label: 'Home',
    ),
    CurvedNavigationBarItem(
      child: Icon(Icons.videocam_outlined),
      label: 'Live Cam',
    ),
  ],
),
```